# ¿Es correcto decir "condenado a de tres a diez años de cárcel"?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario-técnico, preposiciones, lenguaje-jurídico

Leí ayer una noticia que se titulaba:

> Bill Cosby, **condenado de tres a diez años** de cárcel por agresión sexual
>
> <sub>[El País, 25 de septiembre de 2018](https://elpais.com/sociedad/2018/09/25/actualidad/1537899947_545967.html)</sub>

Pasado el rato se cambió por el actual:

> Bill Cosby, **condenado a entre tres y diez años** de cárcel por agresión sexual

Creo fuera de duda que la frase original es incorrecta, pues viene a decir *X, condenado de Y*, que no tiene sentido. Por contra, me surge la duda de si esto sería correcto:

> Bill Cosby, **condenado a de tres a diez años** de cárcel por agresión sexual

Es decir, ¿sería correcta la forma *condenar a <de X a Y> años?*

Comment: No veo por qué no.  Tenemos una preposición de régimen, y después una locución adjetival modificando años.  Para tener problemas, si recuerdo bien, tendría que acabar con dos preposiciones iguales (*condenado a **a** …*), pero tendría que investigarlo.

Answer (score 2):

La primera frase no me suena tan incorrecta, si tomamos *[de](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BtDkacL%7CBtFYznp)* como *desde*, para expresar el posible rango de su condena. La solución que propones no me suena bien, pues se genera una redundancia con las *aes* (*Condenar **a** < de X **a** Y> años*) y tampoco la corrección del periódico puesto que el rango permite que el número de años sea indeterminado (pueden ser 3 años, 5 años y medio, o los 10 años) y la a intentaría mostrar un valor fijo. Es decir, se condena a X años o entre X y Y, pero no a entre X y Y.